# What does observing mean in this case?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, double-slit-experiment, observers

Let us consider a particle emitter which emits a sample of  green colored particles the size of a beach balls and mass of a proton. Now a doubly slit screen is placed in front of this emitter and beyond this screen another screen is placed whose function is to record where it has felt the impact of the particle/wave.

Now consider an observer who views this experiment from the side such that the ball is in this guys FOV all the time during the experiment. However the observer is not consciously focusing on the ball/particle/wave. in this case will the observer affect the outcome of an experiment

Now ignoring how impractical this experiment is will the observers choice of consciously focusing on the green balls change the outcome of the experiment.

[image: A MS Paint depiction of what I have in mind.]

The black lines emanating from the observer's eye is the Field of View for the observer

Comment: Hello. You should understand epistemologically observation as an operation. Since you see the object emitted as "green colored" something, then that object also radiates EM waves and that means you track the orbit of this object all the way to were it finally lands. There will be no interference whatsoever- either if you are giving all of your attention to the object or if you just see it passing with the edge of your eyes.

Comment: I think you are mixing up **consciously and /or unconsciously**, in the interpretion of quantum collapse you are referring to. The object is either observed, or it is not. If it is, then you will see classical behaviour.

Comment: What do you mean by "focus on"?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are misinterperting the physical term *observation*. It is **not**, whether some person is looking at the outcome of an experiment, but rather if information leaves the system in the first place. In your case, as you would like to look at the ball, there must be light present. The measurement happens as the light hits the ball and leaves the system as the photons do. It then does not matter if the photons hit the retina of a person, a detector, or anything else. The information left the system, the coherence is destroyed and we therefore see classical behavior, i.e. no interference pattern.

Comment: +1 but I think you need to explain to the OP, (no offence if this is not new to you Suhrid :), the different interpretations  that we have, otherwise you haven't explained it in the terms it was asked, that is that there might be another way of viewing the experimental results, i.e. briefly explain decoherence...:)

Comment: I see no reason to elaborate on the interpretations as they have no  impact on the main point of the answer. But I added what the consequence of decoherence is.